# Why can't I write this command in multiple lines in a Gitlab job?

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, cicd

here is a job that I wrote where I am trying to use a command that is written in multiple lines.

```
deploy_Snapshot:
  stage: deploy
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH =~ /^develop/
  script:
    - version=$(mvn help:evaluate -Dexpression=project.version -q -DforceStdout)
    - echo "Project version: ${version}"
    - |
      if [[ ${version} != *"SNAPSHOT"* ]]; then 
        echo "Only SNAPSHOT version can be deployed through develop branch.";
      else
        mvn $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS clean deploy -Dmaven.test.skip=true;
      fi
```

[Here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/script.html) is the documentation that I found on GitLab. Using the | (literal) YAML multiline block scalar indicator should solve the problem, but I still get the error.

### Problem

I get the error that says:

> Pipeline cannot be run.
> jobs:deploy_snapshot:script config should be a
> string or a nested array of strings up to 10 levels deep

What is wrong with my script?

Answer (score 2):

The problem was actually in this line

```
- echo "Project version: ${version}"
```

If you use a colon (:) in a script, GitLab might output:

- Syntax is incorrect
- script config should be a string or a nested array of strings up to 10 levels deep

More information is available in the official [Gitlab's documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/script.html#:%7E:text=Troubleshooting-,Syntax%20is%20incorrect%20in%20scripts%20that%20use%20%3A,-If%20you%20use).

Answer (score 1):

The `:` char in your string is confusing the yaml parser this isnt a gitlab problem specifically. If you wrap quotes around your strings that have `:` in them then it will work.

```yaml
deploy_Snapshot:
  stage: deploy
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH =~ /^develop/
  script:
    - 'version=$(mvn help:evaluate -Dexpression=project.version -q -DforceStdout)'
    - 'echo "Project version: ${version}"'
    - |
      if [[ ${version} != *"SNAPSHOT"* ]]; then 
        echo "Only SNAPSHOT version can be deployed through develop branch.";
      else
        mvn $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS clean deploy -Dmaven.test.skip=true;
      fi
```

You can see whats happening if we load this through a yaml parser and print it in python. you end up with a list for the script with the 1st and 3rd item being strings but the 2nd item being a dict

```py
{
  'deploy_Snapshot': {
    'stage': 'deploy', 
    'rules': [
      {'if': '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH =~ /^develop/'}
    ], 
    'script': [
      'version=$(mvn help:evaluate -Dexpression=project.version -q -DforceStdout)', 
      {
        'echo "Project version': '${version}"'
      }, 
      'if [[ ${version} != *"SNAPSHOT"* ]]; then \n  echo "Only SNAPSHOT version can be deployed through develop branch.";\nelse\n  mvn $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS clean deploy -Dmaven.test.skip=true;\nfi'
      ]
    }
  }
```